# win10 dos execute ioinc command issue

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, command, doc

My OS is win10,When I Installed Ionic with run "npm install -g ionic cordova" command,everything looks OK,but when I run "ionic start" command,normally,it should ask and wait me to enter my project name,but it just ask me but not wait me to wait,command quickly end.

"ionic start" command execute like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ionic start

? What would you like to name your project:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

"ionic start ionicstudy" command execute like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ionic start ionicstudy

? What starter would you like to use: (Use arrow keys)
> tabs ............... ionic-angular A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
  blank .............. ionic-angular A blank starter project
  sidemenu ........... ionic-angular A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
  super .............. ionic-angular A starting project complete with pre-built pages, providers and best practices for
 Ionic development.
  conference ......... ionic-angular A project that demonstrates a realworld application
  tutorial ........... ionic-angular A tutorial based project that goes along with the Ionic documentation
  aws ................ ionic-angular AWS Mobile Hub Starter
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I tried to upload ioinc again an again,and restart my computer,but the same.can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

try this ionic start name_of_your_project tabs

*for example*
ionic start myApp tabs
or vists https://ionicframework.com/getting-started for more details.